# CoreBluetooth Peripheral Advertisement on iPod Touch

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, ipod-touch

I am working on an iOS app that connects to bluetooth LE peripherals. When the app discovers the peripheral is reads values from the advertisement data dictionary.

This is the problem: The advertisement data does not contain the `kCBAdvDataLocalName` key if the app is running on an iPod touch. Why is this the case and how can I get this information?

More info: I have tested the application on multiple iPhones and iPod touch devices. The results are consistent for a given central/peripheral pair, but some peripherals do successfully transmit the name in the advertisement data.

Thank you for any help or ideas you can offer.

Comment: I guess you have a 64-bit iPhone but a 32-bit iPod.

Comment: Interesting. Just checked, the iPod touch devices are 6th generation which have ARMv8-A 64-bit processors. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Do you have the same iCloud account on the devices that do get the local name?

Comment: @Paulw11If I understand you correctly, yes. How might that be related to this behavior?